# How android weights coin

Tags: android

Hi i want to know that how can i weight the coin in android phone. I want to develop an application in android where i put the coin on the screen of the device and device will weights the coin and show me the results. there are some application in I-Phone who does this work. Is this possible in the android or not? If possible then how can i implement?

I have lots of research in this topic but i don't get any stuff regarding this please help if you solve this problem.

Comment: Please link to some application in I-Phone who does this work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an [Android metal-detector](http://pocketnow.com/software-1/android-market-pick-metal-detector).
I've used it successfully for ferrous metals, but coins are rarely ferrous.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, no android phones have a built-in digital scale, which would make this task rather impossible...

Comment: Well, do iPhones? According to the question, there are some application in I-Phone who does this work.

Comment: Let's see the iPhone app first. :)

Comment: Would it be at all possible to access the very physics properties of the capacitive or resistive touch screen to do this? If on a resistive screen, we might be able to calculate the overall resistance caused by the weight and calculate the weight (although horrendously inaccurate). Or by capacitive touchscreen determine exactly how much the high frequency signal is attenuated and based on an assumption of the metal's electromagnetic properties, guess at the possible mass (which would be even more horrendously inaccurate)? Though, this is speculative, I'm no electrical engineer.

Comment: hi Nik urls that define this task are http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/real-scale/id352238151?mt=8    http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/scale/id347188711?mt=8

Comment: @Amit, read the reviews for those apps. "This app doesn't even attempt to weigh anything. It's just a joke. I should get my $1.99 back." ... "I see the people giving this 4,5 stars might be cause they work for them. Do not buy don't waste u r 1.00".  Basically, it's not possible because the phone lacks the appropriate hardware.  These apps probably just display a semi-random number from on the accelerometer's change when the coin is placed on the screen.